# "Alert Me" only when a specific user makes an announcement in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I was wondering if there was a way for individual users with contributor access to set their "Alert Me" feature so that when a specific user, ex. the manager, makes an announcement in the announcement web part, it will trigger the "Alert Me", only when the manager posts an announcement.  I'm hoping there is a solution using the workflows in Sharepoint Designer. From what I have read so far, it seems like trying to customize the "Alert Me" is not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a workaround for this, you could create a workflow that notifies you via e-mail when a certain item is created by someone, in this case, your manager, using sharepoint designer workflows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Angelo, but I'm trying to avoid spamming the whole department and focus on people who actually want to "sign up" for the notification

Comment: if this is the case, then you could still use the workflow and just send it to those people, if you don't want to change how the alert me works, what you can do is create a list where you can ask people regarding who wants to sign up for these notifications and then just email it to these people.

Comment: what you can do is create a separate list with only a single entry with people and groups column and then just let them enter their names in (assuming this is connected to an AD) and then refer to this item column when sending out the email

Comment: Yes, that is a great workaround, however, everyone atm has contributor access and people will not like how their "subscriptions" are public. I think I'll have to go with your original workaround. When manager makes an annoucement, send email alert to all staff.